# extract aws lambda exception response in c#

Tags: python, c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function where I am making an api call which returns uuid on success and errorMessage on failure

```
try:
    #make api call 
    return {
                'statusCode': 200,
                'body': json.dumps({'uuid':uniqueuuid})
            }   
except Exception as error:
       return {
                'statusCode': 500,
                'body': json.dumps({'errorMessage':f"P56"})
            }
```

For the success response from lambda, I can able to extract the body values in C#. In the below method,
I can able to get the uuid value returned from lambda. But when there is an exception from lambda, I want to
extract the errorMessage value which is "P56". On exception from lambda, it is picked up by catch block
and the exception has 'remote server returned an error 500' which is correct, but how do I extract the status code and errorMessage value in
the exception block. Or should I return statusCode as 200 for both success and failure from lambda
and extract either uuid or errorMessage in the try block of C#.

C# method:

```
private JObject GetDataFromLambda()
{
    JObject jObj = null;
    try
    {  
     using (var client = new WebClient())
     {
      //define payload data
     var result = client.UploadString($"https://xxx", 
                  WebRequestMethods.Http.Post, data)
     jObj = JObject.Parse(result);
     var uuid= jObj["uuid"].Value<string>();
    }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: Instead of generic `Exception`, catch `WebException`, which includes a `Response` property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webexception?view=net-6.0

Comment: I could see the response property under WebException but how do I extract the status code and response body sent from lambda. I do not see those values under any of the properties

Answer (score 0):

Can you try writing the below code in Lambda?

```
raise Exception('Something is wrong')
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation, something like this should work:

```
private JObject GetDataFromLambda(string data)
{
    JObject jObj = null;
    try
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            //define payload data
            var result = client.UploadString($"https://xxx",
                      WebRequestMethods.Http.Post, data)
            jObj = JObject.Parse(result);
            var uuid = jObj["uuid"].Value<string>();
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError) 
        {
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
            var encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding);
            string json = sr.ReadToEnd();
            var errObj = JObject.Parse(json);

            var httpStatusCode = response.StatusCode;
            var errorMessage = errObj["errorMessage"].Value<string>();
        }
    }
    return jObj;
}
```

Documentation:
`WebException.Response`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webexception.response?view=net-6.0#system-net-webexception-response
`HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream?view=net-6.0#system-net-httpwebresponse-getresponsestream